# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression when updating field

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table where for the same ID I have different information. Ex.

| ID | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 20 |

I want to update the field "Activity", joining all different values of activity for each id as a single row.

When i do the select with the following code is what I want:

```
SELECT string_agg(id_epigrafe, ', ') AS epigrafe_list
                FROM   febrero20_2
                GROUP  BY id_local;
```

The result being:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJgUz.png]

However, when I want to introduce that query in my update query, posgresql (version 13), gives me the following error: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.
The code I am using to trying to update the field is:

```
UPDATE febrero20_2
SET id_epigrafe = (SELECT string_agg(id_epigrafe, ', ') AS epigrafe_list
                FROM   febrero20_2
                GROUP  BY id_local);
```

I have tried to create a new table and in that case I can do it correctly with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE febrero20_3
AS
SELECT id_local, string_agg(id_epigrafe, ', ') AS epigrafe_list
FROM   febrero20
GROUP BY id_local
ORDER BY id_local;
```

Could anyone help me to understand why am I getting that error? I am just new in posgresql and, therefore, I am sorry if it is just some simple error, but I could not find any answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table you update with the table from which you take the values, so that you don't end up with a subquery that has multiple result rows:

```
UPDATE febrero20_2 AS f_1
SET id_epigrafe = f_2.epigrafe_list
FROM (SELECT id_local,
             string_agg(id_epigrafe, ', ') AS epigrafe_list
      FROM   febrero20_2
      GROUP  BY id_local) AS f_2
WHERE f_1.id_local = f_2.id_local;
```

Let me remark that that seems to be a strange statement: you essentially destroy information. Wouldn't it be better to perform such an aggregation when you query from the table?

Comment: Thanks! However, your solution did not work, probably because I did not explain myself clearly. I do not want to join to different tables. I am always working with the same table and I only want to avoid multiple rows for the same field.

The reason behind that is that I want to later check which locals (local_id) have changed activity between years. Through a query, if I say to postgresql that I want to know for each id which locals have different activities in two tables (two years) then I get as a result all combinations between rows that have the same id but different activities.

Comment: Not really. It gives me a sintaxis error in LINE 3: FROM (SELECT id_local,
I have checking if there was an issue with the breackets, but it keeps giving the same error :(

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Fixed.

Comment: That worked!!!!!! THANKS a lot :) I still actually need to learn a lot about sql and posgresql to get to these solutions